# File upload maximum size in php

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I'm implementing a file upload system using cakephp. I'm using php 5.2.5 and cakephp 1.2. Below I have mentioned the maximum file sizes that I have given in php.ini.

```
post_max_size = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 1800M 
memory_limit = 3328M
```

But I need to upload 5 GB files and when I change the file upload sizes to 5GB in php.ini web server doesn't respond. 
Is there any method that I can use to upload 5 GB files to my system? and How can I calculate the maximum size of the file that I can configure in php.ini.

By migrating to php 5.3 will I able to support more capacity for file uploading.

Cheers !!!!

Comment: Most of the time those settings are server based

Comment: Uploading 5gb of data via HTTP is not practical, try FTP.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK uploading 5GB with a HTML-Form is really big. Don't forget that the binary data is normally read in raw 8-bits but the TCP/IP stack only support a 7-bit charset to transport. So all your data is wrapped in another code BASE64 which adds about 40% overhead to your data so it's 6+ GB. I dont't know if upload size should include this overhead but you can try to add this to post max size because according to the documentation post max size should be double the size of upload size. I also to suggest you to use lighttpd + fast-cgi.

Comment: The uploader I'm using here is not just html page. I'm using a flex front end for that

Comment: Maybe you want to use lighttpd + fastcgi.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll check

Comment: Yes, lighttpd has a great performance and the configuration isn't so complicated although the documentation of apache is really big.

Answer (score 0):

And you are going to upload those 5GB using a webform? It would take ages. You should probably use FTP.

Comment: Yes that is what I proposed my client to do (FTP). But he wanted this functionality. Is there any configuration for this?

Comment: I think you have to convince your client that is impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) variable as well, otherwise PHP may exceed the input time while reading the uploaded file, and stop execution.

Use flash uploader (uploadify may do the trick) - because the browser will hang up and won't wait for the server response.

Comment: The thing is Darhazer when I changed these parameters to more that 2000MB web server doesn't execute properly.